# Typescript and React - Higher order component type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to set the type of my higher-order component but I am getting an error that

```
const Component: ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>
JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

Here I am passing the component into the HOC component

```
 <HigherOrderComponent
        Component={ComponentName} setIsTrue={setIsTrue}/>
```

This is my HOC component `ReactElement` and `ReactNode` type is not working.

```
interface HigherOrderComponent {
  Component: ReactElement;
  setIsTrue:Function
}

const HigherOrderComponent = (
  props: EditChannelInfoWrapper,
): ReactElement => {
const {Component} = props;

return (
    <Component {...props}/>
}
```

Comment: `ComponentName` should hold `Component` itself and not just string name

Comment: If i do like this it gives me error that `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'EditChannelInfo': isCollapsed, channelTitle, selectedGame, updateChannelInfo, and 4 more.` ` <EditChannelInfoWrapper
        Component={<EditChannelInfoCollapse />} setIsTrue={setIsTrue}></EditChannelInfoWrapper>`